# ¿Cómo deserealizo un XML a un objeto con Partial Class que generó el xsd.exe?

Tags: vb.net, webservice, xml, serialización, object

Tengo un Web Service que recibe un Xml generado a partir de Star Standard `http://www.starstandard.org`, y tengo que regresar una respuesta también dentro de un Xml estandarizado

Como lo veo, puedo serializar los objetos creados a partir de las clases que generé con el `xsd.exe`, sin embargo para deserializar los Xml que me mandan al Web Service me está dando problemas. Las clases supuestas para deserealizar contienen Partial Class en lugar de Property como elementos del xml, ya que los elementos del Xml contienen Atributos.

Espero puedan darme información a cerca de esto, porque ni en donde trabajo saben como funciona esto jajaja, saludos. Les pongo un ejemplo de un Elemento Xml y su Partial Class correspondiente.

```
<ns:AuthorizationID schemeID="string" schemeName="string" schemeAgencyID="string" schemeAgencyName="string" schemeVersionID="string" schemeDataURI="http://www.sample.com/aris/coniunx" schemeURI="http://www.any.com/claustra/circum">string</ns:AuthorizationID>

<!-- language: lang-vb -->

<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0"),
System.SerializableAttribute(),
System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),
System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"),
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True, [Namespace]:="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5"),
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5", IsNullable:=True)>

Partial Public Class AuthorizationID

Private schemeIDField As String

Private schemeNameField As String

Private schemeAgencyIDField As String

Private schemeAgencyNameField As String

Private schemeVersionIDField As String

Private schemeDataURIField As String

Private schemeURIField As String

Private valueField As String

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
Public Property schemeID() As String
    Get
        Return Me.schemeIDField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.schemeIDField = Value
    End Set
End Property


<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
Public Property schemeName() As String
    Get
        Return Me.schemeNameField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.schemeNameField = Value
    End Set
End Property


<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
Public Property schemeAgencyID() As String
    Get
        Return Me.schemeAgencyIDField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.schemeAgencyIDField = Value
    End Set
End Property

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
Public Property schemeAgencyName() As String
    Get
        Return Me.schemeAgencyNameField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.schemeAgencyNameField = Value
    End Set
End Property

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
Public Property schemeVersionID() As String
    Get
        Return Me.schemeVersionIDField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.schemeVersionIDField = Value
    End Set
End Property

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
Public Property schemeDataURI() As String
    Get
        Return Me.schemeDataURIField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.schemeDataURIField = Value
    End Set
End Property


<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
Public Property schemeURI() As String
    Get
        Return Me.schemeURIField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.schemeURIField = Value
    End Set
End Property

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()>
Public Property Value() As String
    Get
        Return Me.valueField
    End Get
    Set
        Me.valueField = Value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Me voy a responder a mi mismo, aunque todavía no encuentro la solución completa.

Pondré un ejemplo:

```vb
Dim str As String = "<Usuarios>
                     <Usuario>
                     <IdUsuario Value=""EMLL"" Length=""12"" > </IdUsuario>     
                     <Pass Value=""654321"" Length=""5"" ></Pass>
                     </Usuario>
                     <Usuario>
                     <IdUsuario Value=""HJA"" Length=""12""></IdUsuario>
                     <Pass Value=""92092kj"" Length=""12""></Pass>
                     </Usuario>
                     </Usuarios>"

 Dim _Usuarios As UsersModel

 Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(UsersModel))
 Using reader As TextReader = New StringReader(str)
     _Usuarios = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
 End Using
```

Lo siguiente es la clase correspondiente para realizar la deserializacion, si  alguien gusta aportar como agregar a esto, como implementarlo con prefijos y nombre de espacio, se le agradece. :'0

```vb
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

    <Serializable(), XmlRoot("Usuarios")>
    Public Class UsersModel
        <XmlElement("Usuario")> Property Usuarios As New List(Of UserModel)
    End Class

    <Serializable()>
    Public Class UserModel

        Public Property IdUsuario As UsuarioID
        Public Property Pass As Password

    End Class

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute>
    Partial Public Class UsuarioID
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
        Public Property Length As String
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
        Public Property Value As String
    End Class

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute>
    Partial Public Class Password
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
        Public Property Length As String
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
        Public Property Value As String
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, ya logré hacer lo que buscaba, les paso la información por si alguien más no sabe nada de Xml como yo ajajaja.

```vb
Dim XMLResponse As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
XMLResponse.LoadXml(ElementBod.OuterXml)
Dim NameSpace As New XmlSerializerNamespaces
NameSpace.Add("ns", "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5")
Dim StrWriter As New StringWriter
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(type:=GetType(ClaseDelElemento))

Using reader As TextReader = New 
StringReader(XMLResponse.GetElementsByTagName("ns:NombreElemento").Item(0).OuterXml)
 serializer.Serialize(StrWriter, ObjetoDelElemento, NameSpace)
 ObjetoDelElemento = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
End Using
```

ClaseDelElemento = Clase que contiene la información que quieres deserializar del XML.

ObjetoDelElemento = Instancia de ClaseDelElemento

ElementBod = Xml que me envían al WebService.

En éste caso yo recibo un Xml dentro del SoapRequest, y lo tengo que deserializar, por lo que no sé si es correcto crear un StringWriter, ya que no lo uso, tampoco sé si es necesaria la declaración del namespace, sin embargo funciona xP y es lo que ocupo, saludos.